# Return the name of variable with highest value

Tags: javascript

I have a few integer variables.

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
```

I want to know which is the highest (the values are integers/numbers).

I know about Math.max() and I have found some examples of code which do the same thing (pretty much) as Math.max()...these just give the value of the highest value.

I don't care what the actual value is. I just want to know which variable is the highest...I need some code which will return the name of the variable with the highest value.

I have a personality questionnaire. There are three possible outcomes of the questionnaire - angry, mild, cool. The questions are multiple choice (radio buttons) each with three answers to choose from. Each of the three answers corresponds to one of the three personalities... The one which the user chooses most (by selecting the corresponding answers) is the one which is awarded. I need to display this to the user at the end of the quiz....i.e. either "You are angry", "you are mild" or "you are cool".

EXAMPLE QUESTION (THERE ARE SEVERAL OF THESE IN THE TEST)

```
Which best describes your organisation style?<br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="18" value="angry" checked="checked">Good at getting things started, but not good at getting things done.<br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="18" value="mild">Very organised and can focus on a project from start to finish.<br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="18" value="cool">Need help getting things started, but I am good at seeing things to the finish.<br/>


var angry = 0;
var mild = 0;
var cool = 0;

function calculateIt() {

$('#steps input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(i){

    var $this = $(this);
    var itValue = $this.val();

    if (itValue == 'angry') {
        angry = angry + 1;
    }else if (itValue == 'mild') {
        mild = mild + 1;
    }else if (itValue == 'cool') {
        cool = cool + 1;
    }

});



// code to find highest of the three and return the variable name so that
// I can do :

var result = "You are" + THE NAME OF THE HIGHEST VARIABLE

alert(result);
}
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the number of variables a finite (and known) count or are you looking for a generic solution? Also, what good would it do to have the variable name returned? What is the use case?

Comment: yes it will always be 3 variables...I will edit the question to answer not your questions

Answer (score 1):

You really need an object with the names as keys, rather than a list of independently declared variables:

```
var obj = {
    a: 5, b: 3, c: 7
};

function findMax(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var max = keys[0];
    for (var i = 1, n = keys.length; i < n; ++i) {
       var k = keys[i];
       if (obj[k] > obj[max]) {
          max = k;
       }
    }
    return max;
}
```

This will then work regardless of the actual names used.  It also avoids the problem that it's impossible (short of resorting to `eval`) to access a locally declared variable by name.

If the supplied object is empty, the function will return `undefined`.

Comment: I know this is much of useless optimization if the number of keys is low, however Array.prototype.shift is O(n) which would give O(n²) with your algorithm, except if you reverse keys first, then pop them. Oh and +1 btw.

Comment: @aduch that used to be true - I believe it's not in new browsers.  I'll amend anyway.

Comment: I should read some resources about it I must acknowledge I was unaware of this, thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using an object for keeping track of actual variable names (using keys)

For instance

```
// note that I messed with the order of values on purpose
// since objects should not care about keys order
var numericValues = {
    a: 100,
    c: 20,
    b: -2
};

function whichIsTheGreatest(numericValues) {

    var max = -Infinity; // calling Math.max with no arguments returns -Infinity
    var maxName = null;
    for (var key in numericValues) {
       var num = numericValues[key];

       if (num > max) {
           max = num;
           maxName = key;
       }

       max = (num > max && num) || max;
    }

    return maxName;
}

console.log(whichIsTheGreatest(numericValues)); // 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a common construct to sort key-value pairs and return the key with the maximum value:

```
res = [{k:"a",v:a},{k:"b",v:b},{k:"c",v:c}].sort(
function(a,b){
return b.v-a.v
})[0].k
```

Note: the compare function here expects numbers, for other value types please  adjust the compare function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Your code redesigned:

```
var answers = {angry:0,mild:0,cool:0}, res = 'angry'
...
if(++answers[$(this).val()]>answers[res]) {res = $(this).val()}
...
alert(['U R ',res,'!'].join(''))
```

1. define a collection (enables iteration and access using name) and default result value
2. increase the count for the radio value and if this is bigger than the count of the current maximum, change the result value
3. alert the result

Comment: Please explain to the OP as well as future visitors to SO why you did what you did.